# Finding the last row that meets conditions of a mask

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates

This is my dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 333, 444], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20]})
```

I want to create column `c` by using this mask:

```py
mask = (df.a >= df.b)
```

And I want to get the last row that meets this condition and create column `c`. The output that I want looks like this:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20  NaN
2  333  20  NaN
3  444  20  x
```

I tried the code below but it didn't work:

```py
df.loc[mask.cumsum().gt(1) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

Comment: @mandy8055 I think there is something a little bit funny about filling NaN values with NaN. :) But you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a mask to flag the last value satisfying a condition, use `duplicated()` by keeping last. We know that `mask` consists of at most 2 values (True/False). If we can create another mask that flags the last occurrences these values as True, then we can chain it with `mask` itself for the desired mask. This is accomplished by `~mask.duplicated(keep='last')` because `mask.duplicated(keep='last')` flags duplicates as True except for the last occurrence, so its negation gives us what we want.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 333, 444], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20]})
mask = (df.a >= df.b)

df['c'] = pd.Series('x', df.index).where(mask & ~mask.duplicated(keep='last'))
```

If you want to slice/assign, then you can use this chained mask as well.

```py
df.loc[mask & ~mask.duplicated(keep='last'), 'c'] = 'x'
```

---

A shorter version of @mandy8055's answer is to call `idxmax()` to get the index of the highest cum sum (although this is showing a FutureWarning on pandas 2.1.0). As pointed out by @mozway, this works as long as there's at least one True value in `mask`.

```py
df.loc[mask.cumsum().idxmax(), 'c'] = 'x'
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking if the cumulative sum is greater than 1, you should check if the cumulative sum is equal to the maximum cumulative sum value which is equivalent of getting the `mask.sum()`*[suggested by [@Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu)]*.

```
df.loc[(mask.cumsum() == mask.sum()) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://trinket.io/python3/9292ee87e6)***

Comment: `mask.cumsum() == mask.sum()`

Comment: @Onyambu wow thanks. So basically the reason to use it is that `mask.sum()` directly gives us the total number of `True` values in the mask. Please correct me if my understanding for your point is wrong. I haven't thought about it.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See what happens if `df.loc[3, 'a'] = 8`

Comment: Note that it is a reasonably simple fix: `df.loc[(mask.cumsum() == mask.sum()) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'`

Answer (score 4):

you can use last index of mask is True, then change this value to "x" with `at`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 333, 444], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20]})

mask = (df.a >= df.b)
df['c'] = np.nan
last_index = df[mask].index[-1]
df.at[last_index, 'c'] = 'x'

print(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just revert the mask before calling [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the **last** value:

```
mask = (df.a >= df.b)

m = mask[mask][::-1]
if len(m):
    df.loc[m.idxmax(), 'c'] = 'x'
#else:
#    df['c'] = float('nan')
```

Output:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20  NaN
2  333  20  NaN
3  444  20    x
```

Comment: Which answer should I accept? :) You are right. I read your comment.

Comment: Accept whatever your like best. I think the first approach in the currently accepted answer is perfectly fine ;)

Comment: I want to know what is your choice :)

Comment: It depends on your real data. How big is it? Was column "c" preexisting?

Comment: No it does not preexist. My data is very big actually. With Colab resources it may take hours to complete. This code is for wrapping things up at last. To have a final result.

Comment: Then time the different approaches and see for yourself what's best ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255844/discussion-between-amir-and-mozway).